# FloPy 3.3.5 Load model error "list index out of range"

Tags: python, flopy

thanks for reading. I am currently trying to load a MODFLOW6 simulation with the FloPy library and when migrating to version 3.3.5 I receive the following error "IndexError: list index out of range".

The next code run succesfully in FloPy version 3.3.4 like i write before makes and error the version 3.3.5

CODE:

```
#Importar librerias necesarias : OS y FloPy
import os
import sys
import flopy
from flopy.export import vtk
import numpy as np

print(sys.version)
print("flopy version: {}".format(flopy.__version__))

#Nombre del modelo
name = "2_Modelo2_grilla_k"
#Nombre del namefile
nam_file = "2_Modelo2_grilla_k.nam"
#Ruta de la ubicacion de la simulación
model_ws = os.getcwd()
#Ruta de los archivos a importar
model_output = os.path.join(model_ws, "VTKs")
#Ruta de MODFLOW
sim_path = "."

#Imprimimos los valores para verificar que sean correctos
print(model_ws, model_output, nam_file, name, sim_path)

#Carga la simulacion, en este caso los archivos de la simulacion generada por modflow o modelmuse
simulacion = flopy.mf6.MFSimulation.load(
    sim_name=name, exe_name="mf6", sim_ws="."
)

#Carga del modelo
modelo = simulacion.get_model()


print("simulación cargada")
```

The next code is the
ERROR:
`3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`
`flopy version: 3.3.5`
`C:\Users\USUARIO\Downloads\Tutoriales Hidegatari\Modelmuse2\Modelmuse2` `C:\Users\USUARIO\Downloads\Tutoriales Hidegatari\Modelmuse2\Modelmuse2\VTKs` `2_Modelo2_grilla_k.nam 2_Modelo2_grilla_k .`

```
loading simulation...
  loading simulation name file...
  loading tdis package...
  loading model gwf6...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 23>()
     20 print(model_ws, model_output, nam_file, name, sim_path)
     22 #Carga la simulacion, en este caso los archivos de la simulacion generada por modflow o modelmuse
---> 23 simulacion = flopy.mf6.MFSimulation.load(
     24     sim_name=name, exe_name="mf6", sim_ws="."
     25 )
     26 #simulacion = flopy.mf6.MFSimulation.load(sim_name=name, sim_ws=".")
     27 
     28 #Carga del modelo
     29 modelo = simulacion.get_model()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Flopy335\lib\site-packages\flopy\mf6\modflow\mfsimulation.py:715, in MFSimulation.load(cls, sim_name, version, exe_name, sim_ws, strict, verbosity_level, load_only, verify_data, write_headers)
    713     if verbosity_level.value >= VerbosityLevel.normal.value:
    714         print(f"  loading model {item[0].lower()}...")
--> 715     instance._models[item[2]] = model_obj.load(
    716         instance,
    717         instance.structure.model_struct_objs[item[0].lower()],
    718         item[2],
    719         name_file,
    720         version,
    721         exe_name,
    722         strict,
    723         path,
    724         load_only,
    725     )
    727 # load exchange packages and dependent packages
    728 try:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Flopy335\lib\site-packages\flopy\mf6\modflow\mfgwf.py:127, in ModflowGwf.load(cls, simulation, structure, modelname, model_nam_file, version, exe_name, strict, model_rel_path, load_only)
    114 @classmethod
    115 def load(
    116     cls,
   (...)
    125     load_only=None,
    126 ):
--> 127     return mfmodel.MFModel.load_base(
    128         simulation,
    129         structure,
    130         modelname,
    131         model_nam_file,
    132         "gwf",
    133         version,
    134         exe_name,
    135         strict,
    136         model_rel_path,
    137         load_only,
    138     )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Flopy335\lib\site-packages\flopy\mf6\mfmodel.py:795, in MFModel.load_base(cls, simulation, structure, modelname, model_nam_file, mtype, version, exe_name, strict, model_rel_path, load_only)
    792 if model_rel_path and model_rel_path != ".":
    793     # strip off model relative path from the file path
    794     filemgr = simulation.simulation_data.mfpath
--> 795     fname = filemgr.strip_model_relative_path(modelname, fname)
    796 if (
    797     simulation.simulation_data.verbosity_level.value
    798     >= VerbosityLevel.normal.value
    799 ):
    800     print(f"    loading package {ftype}...")

File ~\anaconda3\envs\Flopy335\lib\site-packages\flopy\mf6\mfbase.py:288, in MFFileMgmt.strip_model_relative_path(self, model_name, path)
    286 new_path = ""
    287 for i, mrp in enumerate(model_rel_path_lst):
--> 288     if mrp != path_lst[i]:
    289         new_path = os.path.join(new_path, path_lst[i])
    290 for rp in path_lst[len(model_rel_path_lst) :]:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: looks like a potential bug in flopy, I don't think you'll get an answer on SO unless a flopy dev happens to see it. you may want to open an issue directly with the flopy devs https://github.com/modflowpy/flopy/issues

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to open an issue on github so some flopy dev can see the issue and hopefully help me